# Entity Framework 4 ObjectContext GuideLines

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework-4, entity

I read in a previous article about how to resolve a solution by placing the ObjectContext of my Db in a property within HttpContext.Current.Items["Db"];  This works fantastic, however I have a question.  Does this means that every time I use my repository I have to pass the ObjectContext within HttpContext.Current.Items or do I only need to do this when I am creating or updating an entity that has a reference to another entity.

Within my repository classes I have 2 ways of instantiating them, with a ObjectContext and without one in which the ObjectContext is created there within the entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should share one context among all your repositories used in single HTTP request processing. You should also dispose context at the end of request processing. Generally your repository should not be dependent on HttpContext. The best way is to create ObjectContext outside of your repositories and always pass it to their constructor. You can also do that by using some IoC container like Windsor, StructureMap, Ninject or Unity.

Comment: Thank You, this answers my question exactly and I will be able to make sure I adhere to this early within my project.